# How to find minimum substring out of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, substring

I am trying to find the smallest substring (containing all the values of set) out of string

For example:

```
Input = 'xTxxOxxVxxOxVxxTxxxOxVxTxxxOxxTxVx'
Set = 'OTV'
Output = OxVxT

Input = 'UresqTcdvavUssTss'
Set = 'UT'
Output = UssT
```

Because `OxVxT` is the smallest substring (containing all the element of Set) in example-1, I have written the code for it but its not best method and not working for all examples, I am not exactly finding the smallest substrings through my code, my code is below:

```
def Fun(S, T):
    lst=[]
    lst1=[]
    lst2=[]
    for t in T:
        if t not in S: return False
    T = list(T)
    Z= list(T)
    C = list(T)
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if S[i] in T:
            lst.append(i)
            T.remove(S[i])
        if len(T)==0:break
    print (lst)
    U=(max(lst))
    for u in range(U+1,len(S)):
        if S[u] in Z:
            lst1.append(u)
            Z.remove(S[u])
        if len(Z)==0:break
    print (lst1)
    Q = (max(lst1))
    for u in range(Q+1,len(S)):
        if S[u] in C:
            lst2.append(u)
            C.remove(S[u])
        if len(C)==0:break
    print (lst2)
Str = 'xTxxOxxVxxOxVxxTxxxOxVxTxxxOxxTxVx'
Set = 'OTV'
Fun(Str,Set)
```

I am finding the all possible SubStrings indexes and then finding the distance between them and one with the shortest distance are the smallest substring in the string. My code is not working with all test cases and not giving the right result.

Comment: Please put a few more examples, like inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: @Eddie I updated the example, Input: xHxxRxxxxxHxRx , Set: 'HR' output: HxR

Comment: Try asking this question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You'll get a detailed review of your code there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this runs O(S+T), and needs python 3.7+

```
def Func(S,T):
    s=set(S)
    d={}
    minLen, minBegin=len(T)+1,len(T)+1
    for i,c in enumerate(T):
        if c in s:
            if c in d:
                del d[c]
            d[c]=i
            if len(d)==len(s):
                for k,v in d.items():
                    if i-v+1<minLen:
                        minLen, minBegin=i-v+1,v
                    break
    if minBegin<len(T):
        return T[minBegin:minBegin+minLen]

print(Func('UT', 'UresqTcdvavUssTss')) #Output = UssT
print(Func('OTV', 'xTxxOxxVxxOxVxxTxxxOxVxTxxxOxxTxVx')) #Output = OxVxT
print(Func('A', 'xTxxOxxVxxOxVxxTxxxOxVxTxxxOxxTxVx')) #Output = None
```